# How to save tables, sequences etc in Oracle Database Express 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

This is going to be a really silly question for 99% of people.

I've just started a Database paper (complete novice here) and I'm doing an assignment where I need to design a bunch of tables and add foreign keys, sequences etc.

I've managed to create all of the above in the Oracle express (11g) 'Object Browser' however I need to "provide a SQL script file to define the database schema" and I have no idea how to do that.

I thought there might be some sort of "Save as" or "export to sql script" option somewhere. Have spent the past couple of hours searching the net and trying to figure it out to no avail.

Any help would be very very much appreciated.

Comment: It's not a silly question.  The answer depends on what is available to you.  At one extreme, there is software out there where you can right click on icons and have the script written for you.  At the other extreme you have to type out all the create table sql commands, run them, and save the commands in a text file.  I do both.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for getting back to me. I just assumed that Oracle would have some sort of 'save script' option.
I'm not really able to use any other software here, just using the Oracle Express browser-based application. 
So pretty much I just need to select each thing I want included in the 'Object Browser' and then select the 'SQL' tab and copy the create code?

Comment: I don't have what you are using but it sounds like it might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're learning a RDBMS, you should really write the code that builds the objects instead of using a GUI to do it for you. The `CREATE TABLE` command is quite straightforward, and you'll learn some of the syntax of the Data Definition Language (DDL). The GUI might do this all for you, but you won't *learn* much by doing it that way.